# How to add multidimensional array values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am pretty new to javascript.I am confused with javascript reduce.
this is my array value

```
var result = [ 
            [ 0, 4, 22 ]//26,
            [ 0, 9, 19 ]//28 
           ]
```

I want to add this array value like this..

```
 [
     [26],
     [28]
    ]
```

And again I have to add this value like this..

```
26+28=54
```

this is my try this gives me undefined..

```
var sum = result.map((data) => {
    data.reduce(function (total ,curr) {
        return total+curr
    })
});
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a return statement in block statements

```
var sum = result.map(data => {
    return data.reduce(function (total, curr) {
//  ^^^^^^
        return total + curr;
    });
});
```

or without block statement

```
var sum = result.map(data => data.reduce((total, curr) => total + curr));
```

To answer the last part question, I suggest to create a function for adding values and use it as callback for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var add = (a, b) => a + b,
    result = [[0, 4, 22], [0, 9, 19]],
    sum = result.map(a => a.reduce(add)),
    total = sum.reduce(add);

console.log(sum);
console.log(total);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: In an arrow function with a single expression, there's an implicit `return`.